# Forgot unlock-pattern of android device without registered Google account. Will factory reset work?

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I want to access a Samsung S6 Edge that I haven't used for a long time, 
so I don't care about any data on the device.
I forgot the unlock-pattern and PIN but I **never** registered any Google-Account on it.

What happens if I do a factory reset? Will there be a prompt for a Google account even if there never was one registered on the phone before? Because I don't want to get stuck on that prompt.

Or will the reset go through without any further security issues?

Or is there even a better way to access the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factory reset will work for this issue. But you may lost your data.

I repeat you **may** loss because some cyanogen device didnot delete all data in a factory reset(including my device).

So try it.

Answer (score -1):

Factory reset doesn't give a prompt for a Google account *if there was none configured* before performing it (as in your case), or the one configured was removed. So you can try doing it.